# How to use multiple Pipes in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a CF7 form on my WordPress with multiple email recipients.

I have to use an API with my CF7. The API sends form leads directly into the system we are using. Now the API endpoint is a three lettered example "ABC" which needs to go besides the email and name.

So my form looks like this:

```
[md-select label="location"][select* dept-loc1 include_blank
"Location 1|testloc1@test.com"
"Location 2|testloc2@test.com"
"Location 3|testloc3@test.com"
"Location 4|testloc4@test.com"
[/md-select]
```

When I try to do this; it doesn't work:

```
[md-select label="location"][select* dept-loc1 include_blank
"Location 1|testloc1@test.com|ABC"
..
..
..
[/md-select]
```

I need all the values to pass, location name, email of that location and the API endpoint. Is there a way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: HOw are you using this information?  Is it being used in the the email recipent of your notification mail or just in the mail body?

Comment: There isn't a way to do this, I figured after doing a lot of research. But thank you for responding to the questions. I find another way, had to get rid of the emails. Thanks Aurovrata

Comment: Sure, my question was to uderstand what you're trying to do in order to suggest a way to achieve the result.  Pipes are limited to single level in CF7

Comment: If you are trying to display information in the mail notification, then I suggest you take a look at the [Smart Grid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension for CF7 which provides filters for all mail tags which you can hook and programmatically achieve the results you seek.